# Interpreting Cluster Analysis from SAS Enterprise Miner

Tags: self-study, clustering, sas, text-mining, expectation-maximization

I am currently doing a text mining project and I conducted a clustering analysis in SAS enterprise miner.

I am using the following settings:

[image]

Anyway, The results look like this, showing me different column coordinates (Singular Value Decomposition Values) for each cluster:

[image]

Here are the clusters plotted as x,y coordinates:

[image]

I was wondering if anyone could give me an intuitive explanation for the values in each coordinate column. I know how they are calculated, but it really just goes over my head.

Answer (score 1):

In the absence of more information, no one is going to be able to give you any insight into what "the values in each coordinate column" mean. Since you have the data, you can do this yourself if what you want is a simple, heuristically driven method for deriving insights. Simply run features by cluster means, medians or sums, as appropriate, and pass this into a spreadsheet with the clusters in the columns and the features in the rows being sure to include a "grand mean" (or median) column. By indexing the cluster results to the grand mean for each feature and reranking the features by column indices for each cluster in turn, a profile should emerge as to how the clusters differ from (or are similar to) one another.

Another step that is definitely worth pursuing is to use training and test (or holdout) samples since most clustering algorithms (this includes SVM routines) virtually guarantee solutions that are significantly different for the calibration data. Comparing or projecting the solution onto test data permits development of a misclassification rate, provides evidence for any redundancy in the assignments.

Comment: I guess what I am asking is how to interpret the column values calculated by the SVD routine? In this case we have column values for each cluster of text. What is that column telling me? How close that cluster is to some central point?

Comment: Read it in the EM manual or ask SAS tech support for that